# RESTful service - file name and extension in URL

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I created RESTful service in Oracle apex to get BLOB - images from one table.
Everything goes fine and when I browse my link I get a picture in my browser.

My link goes something like:

https://rfmmitfabizwp2c-bcloud.adb.eu/test123/image
Problem is API service on another side needs this link to be configured in format with filename and extension like:

https://rfmmitfabizwp2c-bcloud.adb.eu/test123/nameofmyimage.jpg

Is there a way to construct a link like this in Oracle Apex RESTful service.
Is there any other way to construct a link like this to retrieve my blob image column from a table in database.

Comment: What version of APEX and ORDS are you currently using?

Comment: @EJEgyed Its on Oracle cloud , APEX version 22.1.4  , ORDS version 22.3.0.r2781755

Comment: added the oracle-ords tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your REST API template just needs to be

```
test123/:file_name
```

And then in your GET handler code, the SQL needs to have a WHERE clause that says, OK here's the file I actually want. This assumes you're storing the file name along with the file in your table.

Here's an example -

[image]

[More details here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2022/10/downloading-files-in-oracle-by-name-via-rest-apis/)

The handler code -

```
ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
      p_module_name    => '101',
      p_pattern        => 'files/:file_name',
      p_method         => 'GET',
      p_source_type    => 'resource/lob',
      p_items_per_page => 25,
      p_mimes_allowed  => NULL,
      p_comments       => NULL,
      p_source         => 
'select mime_type, the_file
from blobs
where FILE_NAME = :file_name');
```

Obviously the SQL needs updated to match your table & column definitions.

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am the product manager for ORDS.*

Comment: Thank you my service is working now. Working just like you said.

Comment: is it possible to have Content-Length in the header. I have some issues with pictures, for example image preview not working in Viber messages

Comment: yes, but then we're going to get more interesting. you're going to write a pl/sql block to get the LOB and print it, and then run another query to get the size of the LOB and then assign that to your header

Comment: @Octavarium I updated my answer to get you started on the response header you were asking about.

Comment: i used that procedure in my handler and changed source to PL/SQL , In postman when i call my link   I see picture but in header still don't see content- length.

Comment: All I can is 'it worked for me' and you may need to debug your proc - is vLENGTH getting computed, etc.

Comment: thank you for help, i found similar issue on oracle support https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2125804_1.html seems that its not possible to pass that header

Comment: I debugged my procedure, variable hold size value. ,Content-Disposition and Content type are ok only content-length not showing. Maybe it is because my service is on cloud.

Comment: if you use plsql gateway you'll get the header, but on the REST API code path side of ORDS, we use chunked transfer encoding...Using Content-Length and Chunked transfer encoding are mutually exclusive per the HTTP spec. You use Content-Length you cannot used Chunked transfer encoding.

Comment: I understand, this is only thing left in my project to be successful . Is there a way for my image to be visible on link with plsql gateway.

Comment: yes of course https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/download-files-using-plsql-and-a-gateway